# c++ headers between projects

Tags: c++, clr, llvm, header-files

I run in trouble when writing application in c++. I have got two projects. Project A is ordinary c++ project, project B is c++ project with clr support. Project A contains classes that uses headers from LLVM framework. Project B contains managed wrappers for some classes of project A. Can I use classes from project A in project B without including their headers?

The reason is this. When I include class headers from project A in project B I need to specify also framework libraries that this header from project A uses, but LLVM framework cannot coop with clr support. I cannot moved framework includes from header to cpp file. How can I solve it?

Comment: You have to use the headers -- otherwise how will your source file know how to use each class?   I think the only way you'll get around this issue is to use the preprocessor.

Comment: As long as you don't need to use LLVM and clr together you can use forward declarations. Headers just declare variables and functions that are present in another source file and put them in the class the header is included in so the code knows of the existance of these functions and variables. Unless of course the headers are massive and you don't want to forward declare everything, or create another header that doesn't include the incompatible headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can as long as you don't use templates in project A that depends on LLVM headers. You can always forward declarate the types you are using in project A headers and include the actual headers in the cpp files.

Say there is a type you want to use called `llvm_type`  that is a class defined by the libraries of the LLVM compiler. In `projectA.h` you can do like this:

```
class llvm_type;

class MyAPrjClass {
public:
    void myMethod (llvm_type x, int y);
}
```

Then in your `projectA.cpp` you include the LLVM header:

```
#include <llvm_type.h>

void MyAPrjClass:: myMethod (llvm_type x, int y)
{
    // Define your method using the llvm_type here.
}
```

The same can be done for structs, containers and other types as long as you forward declarate them. Suppose for example you want to use a `std::vector<int>` that is part of the LLVM compiler. In this case you declare in your header something like `class VectorInt;` to define prototypes and in your cpp you write:

```
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<int> VectorInt;
```

and use it in your method definitions.

What you can't do is define template classes or methods that depend on LLVM headers because you need to define the methods in the same headers and that will involve knowing the implementation of the imported types.

Comment: Well I tried this even before I asked question. Nevertheless I tried it again, but now it got me on the right track. It seems that LLVM is very strict about includes. Some of my includes have to be in header file (all headers that are not for LLVM and not for custom classes), some of them have to be in cpp file (all LLVM headers and all custom classes) and I cannot use windows.h. For some reason it collides with one (yes only one) core LLVM file. Thank you for your advice, you really helped me solve this.